# Can't set up a simple app

Tags: facebook, configuration

I can't set up my first app.

It's a just 'hello world' php located at: http://www.mysite.com/apps/myphp.php

Display Name: My App
Namespace: myapp
Sandbox Mode: Yes

--

Canvas URL: http://www.mysite.com/apps/

Save changes...

--

Then in my apps tab I found the apps's detalis and using the 
https://apps.facebook.com/123645844460042/ I get that tha page is not found.

What am I missing, I supposed that when I go to the url above I will find my Hello world.
Hope anyone can help me.
Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, even the link you presented does not exist: http://www.mysite.com/apps/myphp.php - i get a "page not found" error.

Second, why did you set your canvas URL to a different one? it would only work if there is any index.php (or index.html) in the folder, but i also get "page not found".

No offense, but before starting with Facebook Apps, you should get some knowledge in other things (Web Servers, PHP, ...)

Btw, also keep in mind that you need a server with SSL certificate for Facebook Apps.

Comment: Hi lusch, actually http://www.mysite.com/apps/myphp.php was just an example for my set up thay will be http://www.clicktek.com/apps/myphp.php.

Comment: well: "The requested URL /apps/myphp.php was not found on this server."

Comment: Hi lush, thanks for your time,  http://www.mysite.com/apps/myphp.php was just an example for the location of my file. Problem was that I didn't know that it was looking for an index.php. Thanks budie and I will take your advise. Greetings.